# Custom events in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I know this has been discussed a lot on SO, but even based on the previous questions and answers I still can't quite understand the details of how event logging is really supposed to work in Firebase.

Let's say somewhere in my code I have this:

```
FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("card_id", 912);
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("card_open", bundle);
```

Do I understand correctly that the "card open" even should now appear in Firebase Console with the "card_id" parameter?

Then I click More > Edit parameter reporting, enter the name of the parameter I added in my code, and it should appear on the list.

I have read the docs several times, but I still can't get it. Can I not even use any of the events and parameters provided by FirebaseAnalytics.Param and FirebaseAnalytics.Event and just send custom events/parameters (within the known limits, of course).

Another question is whether the limit on the number of global parameters force you to use Big Query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct. You should see the card_open event with card_id parameter in the analytics console.

Note that there's a delay in the analytics reporting, about 4 to 6 hours after it was logged and uploaded by the device.

Just to ensure that your implementation is correct. I mean, to verify that the events, parameters and user properties are logged in the right time and the right place correctly, use the [DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) console.

I also believe that you should be able see the card_id parameter in the custom reporting for card_open event, considering the delay in the reporting.

For your last question, the parameter limit is on a project level perspective now, compared before that it was per app. Parameters with the same name across different apps will be counted as 1. Not sure, maybe Firebase would like us (developers) to use the parameters accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for answering. There's one more question concerning how the number of parameters is counted. 
Let's say there are two different events event_1 and event_2 both of which have a custom parameter - event_parameter. 

As far as I understand, the number of available parameters will be reduced by two, not one.  For this reason, even if I have plenty of events with the same parameter used I will still run out of the limits and need to use BiqQuery. Is that correct?

Comment: If you have event_1 and event_2 with both event_parameter, that will be counted as 2. On the other hand, if you have event_1 with event_parameter in app 1 and event_1 with event_parameter in app 2, then it will be counted as 1. If you run out of limits, AFAIK, there's no way to increase it. BigQuery is used if you'd like to perform custom analysis with your raw analytics data, once it's exported.

Comment: Okay, then another question. Here's a quote from the Firebase documentation. 

"You can also identify up to 50 custom event parameters per project (40 numeric and 10 textual) to include in reporting by registering those parameters with their corresponding events."

If I understand the paragraph correctly, there should be one counter for all apps within a project. Nevertheless, when I switch between apps in my projects, there are two independent counters. It just doesn't make sense to me. What am I getting wrong?